# Cant parse json and get Unexpected token in JSON

Tags: php, android, json

I use php to send data from server to my android app. The code run any error in php but I get error in android app that I can't parse json. I elicit the json and toke it to http://json.parser.online.fr/ and it shows me SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0 error 
This is my php code:

```
function selectAll($cnn)
{
    $query="SELECT * FROM user";
    $stmt=$cnn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

     $result[]=$row;

    }
    return $result;
    }
echo(json_encode(array('result' => $arr)));
```

[and This is my json data that generated with php](http://paste.ofcode.org/KxDRZEf6udzC49SPdmBGFt)

and of course this is my android code:

```
public class ManageUser extends AppCompatActivity  implements RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    List<user> listOfUser=new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_manage_user);
        progressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.UserProgress);
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recviewUser);
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this,this));
        SelectAllUserNetworkTask GetAllUser=new SelectAllUserNetworkTask(this);
        GetAllUser.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View childView, int position) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Clicked trigger",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemLongPress(View childView, int position) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"LongPress",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public class SelectAllUserNetworkTask extends AsyncTask {

        Context myContext;
        List<user> productarray =new ArrayList<>();
        private OkHttpClient client=new OkHttpClient();
        public  String Result;
        public SelectAllUserNetworkTask(Context context)
        {
            this.myContext=context;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
            try {
                RequestBody requestBody;
                requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                        .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                        .addFormDataPart("action","select")

                        .build();

                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(Tags.UserAddress)
                        .post(requestBody)
                        .build();

                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                Result=response.body().string().toString();
                 String str=Result.substring(Result.indexOf("{"), Result.lastIndexOf("}"));
                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(str);

                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");

                for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) {
                    JSONObject jobject =  jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    user myUser =new user();

                    myUser.setUsId(jobject.getInt("id"));
                    myUser.setName(jobject.getString("name"));
                    myUser.setLastName(jobject.getString("lastname"));
                    myUser.setEmail(jobject.getString("email"));
                    myUser.setPassword(jobject.getString("password"));
                    myUser.setImage(jobject.getString("image"));
                    myUser.setGender(jobject.getString("gender"));
                    myUser.setBirthDay(jobject.getString("birthday"));
                    myUser.setFavFilm(jobject.getString("favFilm"));
                    myUser.setFavColor(jobject.getString("favColor"));
                    myUser.setAboutMe(jobject.getString("aboutme"));
                    myUser.setAdmin(jobject.getInt("admin"));
                    productarray.add(myUser);
                }
              /*  Type typeList=new TypeToken<List<ModelProduct>>(){}.getType();
                productarray=new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject.getString("result"),typeList);*/

                listOfUser = productarray;
                return productarray;

            }  catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return  null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
            super.onPostExecute(o);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(myContext);
            llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

            UserAdapter ca=new UserAdapter(listOfUser,myContext);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(ca);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The PHP code is not relevant, what is your Android code for parsing the JSON object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should  change this line

```
 echo(json_encode(array($arr)));
```

to

```
 echo(json_encode(array('result'=>$arr)));
```

because you are accessing result during parsing and that is not there in php

Comment: I changed that  but i still get exception in android on this line JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(Result);

Answer (score 0):

First thing, your JSONResponse is in the form of a JSONArray and  not JSONObject. Therefore casting the response to a JSONArray is going to give you parsing error.

Second, I don't see any "result" in the JSON response that you are getting.

Comment: I exactly get exception on JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(Result); what should i have to do instead. as u know this is String and we just JSONObject To convert

Comment: And also i do this method to handle json array format and it worked for me before

Comment: JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

Where "response" is the string you received from the server once you call that API method.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code  :

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM Students");
$output = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$record = array();
$record['id'] = $row['Id'];
$record['name'] = $row['Name'];
$record['phone'] = $row['Phone'];
$output[] = $record;
```

}
echo json_encode($output);

and in android side :

```
          String res ;
          JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(res);
          JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
          for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) {
                JSONObject jobject =  jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                user myUser =new user();
                myUser.setUsId(jobject.getInt("id"));
                myUser.setName(jobject.getString("name"));
                myUser.setAdmin(jobject.getInt("phone"));
                productarray.add(myUser);
            }
```

i hope this work for you ;